# Error building counter-kernal

Tags: smart-rollup

I am getting this error always when I try building a counter-kernel.

Command:

```
cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

Error:

```
error: failed to build archive: section too large

The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: In file included from /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/server.c:22:
warning: In file included from /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/vect.c:10:
warning: /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/no_asm.h:943:1: warning: argument 'ret' of type 'vec256' (aka 'unsigned int[8]') with mismatched bound [-Warray-parameter]
warning: CT_INVERSE_MOD_IMPL(256)
warning: ^
warning: /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/no_asm.h:939:45: note: expanded from macro 'CT_INVERSE_MOD_IMPL'
warning: inline void ct_inverse_mod_##bits(vec##bits ret, const vec##bits inp, \
warning:                                             ^
warning: /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/vect.h:142:32: note: previously declared as 'vec512' (aka 'unsigned int[16]') here
warning: void ct_inverse_mod_256(vec512 ret, const vec256 inp, const vec256 mod,
warning:                                ^
warning: In file included from /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/server.c:22:
warning: In file included from /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/vect.c:10:
warning: /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/no_asm.h:944:1: warning: argument 'ret' of type 'vec384' (aka 'unsigned int[12]') with mismatched bound [-Warray-parameter]
warning: CT_INVERSE_MOD_IMPL(384)
warning: ^
warning: /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/no_asm.h:939:45: note: expanded from macro 'CT_INVERSE_MOD_IMPL'
warning: inline void ct_inverse_mod_##bits(vec##bits ret, const vec##bits inp, \
warning:                                             ^
warning: /Users/sanket/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/blst-0.3.10/blst/src/vect.h:140:32: note: previously declared as 'vec768' (aka 'unsigned int[24]') here
warning: void ct_inverse_mod_383(vec768 ret, const vec384 inp, const vec384 mod,
warning:                                ^
warning: 2 warnings generated.
warning: warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: archive library: /Users/sanket/Personal-Projects/TezsoSORU/counter-kernel/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/blst-2d660fbff66913b1/out/libblst.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)

error: could not compile `blst` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

Can someone explain me where I am going wrong?

Update:
Now I am getting this error

```
sanket@SANKETs-MacBook-Air 06_counter_kernel % cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
   Compiling tezos-smart-rollup v0.1.0 (https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos#4a89056e)
error: couldn't read /Users/sanket/.cargo/git/checkouts/tezos-c5ed5e9e8d02562c/4a89056/src/kernel_sdk/sdk/src/../README.md: No such file or directory (os error 2)
 --> /Users/sanket/.cargo/git/checkouts/tezos-c5ed5e9e8d02562c/4a89056/src/kernel_sdk/sdk/src/lib.rs:5:10
  |
5 | #![doc = include_str!("../README.md")]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `include_str` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: could not compile `tezos-smart-rollup` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of additional build requirements when on MacOS.

The steps are mentioned in the `tezos-smart-rollup` sdk [docs](https://docs.rs/tezos-smart-rollup/0.1.0/tezos_smart_rollup/#installing-clang), but to summarise:

You need to install `LLVM` through homebrew, rather than using the default version. The specific 'section too large' error can then be fixed by using the `llvm_ar` that is installed alongside:

```
brew install llvm
LLVM_PATH=$(brew --prefix llvm)
export AR="${LLVM_PATH}/bin/llvm-ar"
export CC="${LLVM_PATH}/bin/clang"
```

After which point you should be able to build successfully.

Comment: I already tried this. Still I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

In `cargo.toml` file I had crate `tezos-smart-rollup = { git = "https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos" , features = ["testing"] }`.

Replacing this with `tezos-smart-rollup = { git = "https://gitlab.com/marigold/tezos", rev = "046281d4494560ed96796bd7ffe9053e573654f3" }` worked for me.

Alternatively, you can also use
`tezos-smart-rollup = {version = "0.1.0", features = ["testing"]}`

Comment: You can use direct from crates.io instead: tezos-smart-rollup = { version = "0.1.0", features = [" testing"]}

Comment: Yess, this helped.